# flutter calendar with drop down month and drop down year in header and week days in body

Tags: flutter

I have tried the table calendar package  but it's not helping me solve the problem i need to get month drop-down and year drop-down in 1 row and below week section with days being displayed

Comment: Please share your code or some sample code, so it will be easier for respondents to understand your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.